# Unable to access IoT Core page on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot

Whenever i tap on IoT Core on GCP following error popups
**There was an error while loading /iot/registries?authuser=1&project=qwiklabs-gcp-02-84d4844edd8d. Please try again.**

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to access to a resource wich is not accesible through the Qwiklab that you are currently doing.

Take care, if you use resources that are not related to the lab, you could be locked out of the lab and lose your work.